# Method evaluates indefinitely

Tags: angular

Can you tell me why this method `getAlphabetCharacter()` gets evaluated indefinitely even though it's having only 2 items (`0` and `1`)? How can I avoid it?

[**Video about the issue**](https://youtu.be/2M46Mwoub9s)

**.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let i of inputs;let index = index">
  <ion-label><span>{{getAlphabetCharacter(index)}}</span></ion-label>
  <ion-radio value="{{index}}" (ionSelect)="toggleChoiceOther(i.label)"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
 getAlphabetCharacter(index: number): string {
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
  }


this.inputs= [
        {
            "encode": "M",
            "display": "He",
            "label": "gender"
        },
        {
            "encode": "F",
            "display": "She",
            "label": "gender"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: What's the `inputs` content?

Comment: Please see the update @developer033

Comment: *Method evaluates indefinitely*. Yes, it happens when you call a method this way in template. It's normal behavior.. For more explanation see [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081810/angular2-infinite-loop-when-i-call-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-templa). So, what you could do is to use **Array#map** and create a new property for every object *alphaChar* (something like this), so you can access `i.alphaChar` in template. Check this [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0u0xfYoGoUSMEPjCojfp?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks.Can you please put this as an answer? @developer033

Comment: I just posted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Method evaluates indefinitely

It's normal behavior when you call a method this way in template.

For more explanation see [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081810/angular2-infinite-loop-when-i-call-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-templa).

In order to solve your problem, you could use **Array#map** and create a new property for every object (something like `alphaChar`), so you can access `i.alphaChar` in *template*, as below:

***Component:***

```
this.inputs.map((elem, i) => elem.alphaChar = this.getAlphabetCharacter(i));
```

***Template:***

```
<ion-label><span>{{i.alphaChar}}</span></ion-label>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0u0xfYoGoUSMEPjCojfp?p=preview)</kbd>

**EDIT#1 (Not really related to the original question):**

I noticed that you're using *multiple* radio buttons, so you must wrap them with the `radio-group` *attribute*, as described in [**docs**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/):

```
<ion-list radio-group>
  <ion-list-header>
    Alphabet
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let i of inputs;let index = index">
    <ion-label><span>{{i.alphaChar}}</span></ion-label>
    <ion-radio [value]="index" (ionSelect)="toggleChoiceOther(i.label)"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wJoxmOt66x0CkC2loHO9?p=info)

Also, if you want to bind the selected value to a variable, just add `[(ngModel)]` at same level of `radio-group` *attribute*.

**Ex:**

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="myVariable">...</ion-list>
```

Comment: I have a small problem here.You can see that my HTML template where it uses `i.label` too.How can I get that when I return only one variable from the `map` method?

Comment: On your plunker where I cannot select the radio buttons too?

Comment: *How can I get that when I return only one variable from the map method?* Nope, you aren't returning only one variable from the `map`. You're creating a new *property* for every object in your `array`. Please, check the update.

Comment: Excellent.Thank you so much :)