# How to check if two different child dropdowns has the same value in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have two different dropdowns (implemented a as a cihld components) with the same data inside.

I want to display mat-error if those two selected values are the same. On a mat-error tag, I call a function:

```
areValuesTheSame() {
  if (this.form.controls['value1'].value && this.form.controls['value2'].value) {
      return this.form.controls['value1'].value === this.form.controls['value2'].value;
}
```

I thought that I will get the result true/false and according to that in a mat-error I will do like this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="areValuesTheSame()">Selected values has to be the same!</mat-error>
```

But the thing is, that it constantly returns the values for me instead of returning it one time (true or false).

If I try to check it in the console.log, the console prints the result n times (like an infinite loop).

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: where do u put your console.log?

Comment: I put my console.log  instead of "return" to see how it actually works.

Comment: The "proper" Angular way would be to make `areValuesTheSame` a validator (it'll run when something happens to inputs, not on every change detection). https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 1):

Actually its nothing wrong with your code. Its how Angular works. It runs change detection automatically, and when changes are checked it runs your function.

Check this: [angular2 - infinite loop when i call method from a Angular 2 class inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081810/angular2-infinite-loop-when-i-call-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-templa)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called on every change detection cycle, to avoid that behavior, put a boolean inside your *ngIf and change it on value change of your value1 and value2, for example, on a (keyup) event

```
<input formControlName="value1" (keyup)="areSame()" />
<input formControlName="value2" (keyup)="areSame()" />
<mat-error *ngIf="!sameBool">Selected values has to be the same!</mat-error>
```

TS:

```
areSame(){
 if(this.form.controls['value1'].value === this.form.controls['value2'].value)
   sameBool= true;
}
```

EDIT: using Validators as mentioned in the comments is even better.