# Iterating Promise<any[]> with *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

Getting an infinite loop trying iterate through the promise resulting from this function call:

```
 public CUSTOMERS = [
    {"id":1,"name":"Crypto Joe", "description":"Love Crypto in the Morning"},
    {"id":1,"name":"Crypto Sue", "description":"Love Crypto in the Evening"}
];

    loadCustomers():Promise<any[]> {
      return of(this.CUSTOMERS).toPromise()
    }
```

And this is the template:

```
<li *ngFor="let customer of loadCustomers() | async">
    <h3>{{customer.name}}</h3>
    <code> {{customer.description}} </code>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thoughts?  This is a stackblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimal-angular-ngfor-loop

I updated the demo to use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` but it still results in an infinite loop.  Perhaps this can only be done with observables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular2 - infinite loop when i call method from a Angular 2 class inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081810/angular2-infinite-loop-when-i-call-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-templa)

Comment: Also considering you consume the `Promise` via `async` pipe you might as well just provide an observable (`return of(this.CUSTOMERS);`). The `async` pipe handles this just as fine.

Comment: I changed the original demo to use `  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
` but it does not work.  Any idea why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081810/angular2-infinite-loop-when-i-call-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-templa#comment73324153_43122416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is the change detection.
So as soon as the first customer is added to the DOM angular detects the change and recalls loadCustomers() which results in a infinite loop.

Either change detection to "OnPush" or bind to a property instead of a method or getter.

Comment: Cool - Binding the property works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimal-angular-ngfor-loop-with-promise

Comment: I changed the original demo to use `  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
` but it does not work.  Any idea why?

Comment: As Philipp Meissner already mentioned consider using observable instead of promise.
so you simply use of(this.CUSTOMERS) and the property will be of type customer$: Observable<any[]>. Glad i could help

Comment: I you want to use change detection you would manually have to trigger the change detection.
Inject ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor and call changeDetection.detectChanges().
This triggers the render anew